# How am I supposed to use the TF model garden beta API?

Tags: tensorflow

The TF garden library provides vision-related beta features in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision/beta.
I am using this because the training of ResNet-RS model is known to be able in this library. However, the API seems to have a very different interface and internal mechanisms from the original API(image classification in particular). Especially, they are not documented and the code seems to be updated almost every day. The `README.MD` file contains a single sentence: `This directory contains the new design of TF model garden vision framework.`

Are users supposed to use the beta API? Or are they a work-in-progress and do I need to make a custom implementation? Is there documentation somewhere else?

Comment: Did you work out what to do in the end?